# asp.net database connectivity

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please take a look at the following code.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    if (DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text == "Economy")
    {
        seats = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);

        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select easeats from flight where fno='" + fn + "'";
       int eds = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (eds > seats)
        {
            Panel2.Visible = true;                //seats available
            cl = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;  
            seat = seats.ToString();
            seats = eds;
        }
        else
        {
            Panel3.Visible = true;         // seats not available 
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I am getting error in the line:`int eds = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

And the error is

> error in converting varchar value to datatype int

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: what is the type of easeats  in database ? ExecuteScalar is usually used to get count, It returns first column of the first row of the result set, may be the result you are getting is null and that is why you are having problem. Please tell us the type of easeats in db and what it it is returning if you run the query in the database

Comment: @user... wow the code quality is so poor here, I hope I will never have to take any of the planes of that company you are making the website for... :) kidding... :D

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, NEVER construct your query like this. Use parameterized queries instead.

Secondly, the error message is quite clear - you're trying to convert to int some varchar column, that probably contains some literal characters as well and not only numbers...

Thirdly, prefer "using" statements over explicitly closing the connection. It's more safe that way.

Answer (score 2):

try to replace:

```
int eds = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

with:

```
int eds = 0;

int.TryParse(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), out eds);
```

in this way if the Convert fails you have no issues and continue with eds = 0...

side note, your handling of exceptions and connection lifetime is very poor, think about replacing the whole block in this way:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        if (DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text == "Economy")
        {
            seats = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);

            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "select easeats from flight where fno='" + fn + "'";

            int eds = 0;
            object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
            int.TryParse(result, out eds);

            if (eds > seats)
            {
                Panel2.Visible = true;                //seats available
                cl = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;  
                seat = seats.ToString();
                seats = eds;
            }
            else
            {
                Panel3.Visible = true;         // seats not available 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

of course, anyway, you should also consider to refactor the whole thing and separate clearly database and business logic from UI logic, in general you should never deal directly with connections and queries inside the UI and even less in a `ButtonClick` event handler.

Comment: i am getting an error in the line:

int.TryParse(result, out eds);

.. it has some invalid arguements; TryParse(String, out int)

Comment: after you assign the result object from the query check for null and call try parse with result.ToString(), after you checked result is not null.

Comment: i am getting an error in the line:
 int.TryParse(result, out eds); 
.. it has some invalid arguements; TryParse(String, out int) –